# How to purge out a package that I have build with catkin?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have build a package (in ROS hydro) with catkin, now I wish to purge (delete all of it, including configuration files and executable)  it out completely, is there a catkin facility to do so ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175162/how-to-purge-out-a-package-that-i-have-build-with-catkin-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2014-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not anything built into any of the tools to do this. If you are doing `catkin_make_isolated` then you can just delete the build folder for the package in `build/<package name>` and the `devel`/`install` folders. Then remove the source code for that package or drop a `CATKIN_IGNORE` file in the source code of the that package and then rebuild. This will be relatively fast since the build folder for all of the other packages are preserved.

If you are using `catkin_make`, the packages are all combined, so the only way is to remove it from the workspace is to remove or disable the source code and then delete the `build`, `devel`, and/or `install` folders and rebuild the whole workspace.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-06-26**:
@William  That would be really messy ! shouldn't we have a tool like that ? or is it against catkin philosophy ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-06-26**:
It's not against any philosophy, but there are technical problems to how it would be implemented, can you suggest a way to remove one package from a target installation when multiple have been installed there?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-06-26**:
@William Okay - this is a shot in the bush ! since catkin_make gives a detailed list of the installation (on the terminal window) as it installs, there should be a way to keep a track of what all it installs, so that can be starting point. I am trying to draw a comparison with apt-get in Ubuntu.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-06-26**:
Just playing the devil's advocate, what happens if two packages install the same file, and then you remove one of the packages, do you leave the file they both installed?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-06-26**:
@William dude ! I like Al Pacino, but dare not get into his shoes ! ;-)